# How get latitude and longitude from a kml file in PHP

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to obtain the  list of cells in a specified area  whit OpeCellID. I can get it writing:

```
http://www.opencellid.org/cell/getInArea?key=9f84179c-73f7-4694-9121-5bcb90e03608&BBOX=3.389,-76.5244777931681607,3.3764334069836786,-76.5119112001518393&mcc=732&mnc=123&lac=4003
```

And it give me a kml file whit this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
<name>OpenCellID Cells</name>
<description>List of available cells</description>
<Placemark><name></name><description><![CDATA[lat: <b>3.378199</b><br/>lon:      <b>-76.523528</b><br/>mcc: <b>732</b><br/>mnc: <b>123</b><br/>lac: <b>4003</b><br/>cellid: <b>26249364</b><br/>averageSignalStrength: <b>0</b><br/>samples: <b>10</b><br/>changeable: <b>1</b>]]></description><Point><coordinates>-76.523528,3.378199,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark>
<Placemark><name></name><description><![CDATA[lat: <b>3.382578</b><br/>lon: <b>-76.518148</b><br/>mcc: <b>732</b><br/>mnc: <b>123</b><br/>lac: <b>4003</b><br/>cellid: <b>26251342</b><br/>averageSignalStrength: <b>0</b><br/>samples: <b>11</b><br/>changeable: <b>1</b>]]></description><Point><coordinates>-76.518148,3.382578,0</coordinates></Point> </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I need to obtain specifically the latitude, longitude and the cell Id to each cell in a php file, because a want to make a map in google maps later.

How can I get this information ?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you clarify which language you'll use to parse the KML file? It seems like PHP, but it's hard to tell from your question. If PHP, you should look into reading the KML file with a library (e.g. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)

Comment: Are you asking how to get the contents of the KML file into your PHP script or how to parse it? Or both?

Comment: I'm asking how to get the contents of the KML file in my PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the KML into your script one answer as already suggested is to use the [XMLReader class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) which can open a URI for reading.

If you really just want the XML as a string then look into the `curl` library. You should be able to easily find a load of tutorials on using either of these options, especially curl.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$url="PUT YOUR URL LINK";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($xml)

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation to your code / answer. That way you can improve it and help the questioner learning how this works.